# SecurityException user -1 instead of 0

Tags: android, flutter

Hey after upgrading flutter I get this SecurityException. I do not know how to resolve it. it does not appear with an emulator. Can you please help me?

I already checked the manifest and checked for the splash screen.

its an samsung s8 and it does not have the newest OS
it also does not work on an samsung s7

flutter doctor -v shows no issues

and after flutter clean (+deleting build) It runs on the next installation fine. But after that it does not work again.

```
I/e.pinkdrive.ap(13480): Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
I/flutter (13480): 4
I/FLTFireBGExecutor(13480): Creating background FlutterEngine instance, with args: [--start-paused, --enable-dart-profiling]
I/FLTFireMsgService(13480): FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService started!
D/vndksupport(13480): Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
E/flutter (13480): [ERROR:flutter/fml/platform/android/jni_util.cc(182)] java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: broadcast from android asks to run as user -1 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL or android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
E/flutter (13480):  at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1966)
E/flutter (13480):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1934)
E/flutter (13480):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1884)
E/flutter (13480):  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.reportActivityFullyDrawn(IActivityManager.java:7318)
E/flutter (13480):  at android.app.Activity.reportFullyDrawn(Activity.java:2092)
E/flutter (13480):  at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onFlutterUiDisplayed(FlutterActivity.java:1061)
E/flutter (13480):  at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$1.onFlutterUiDisplayed(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:88)
E/flutter (13480):  at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView$2.onFlutterUiDisplayed(FlutterView.java:133)
E/flutter (13480):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.onFirstFrame(FlutterJNI.java:461)
E/flutter (13480):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter (13480):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
E/flutter (13480):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:181)
E/flutter (13480):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
E/flutter (13480):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (13480):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
E/flutter (13480):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
E/flutter (13480): Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
E/flutter (13480):  at com.android.server.am.UserController.handleIncomingUser(UserController.java:1818)
E/flutter (13480):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:25752)
E/flutter (13480):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:25683)
E/flutter (13480):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:26553)
E/flutter (13480):  at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcastAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1264)
E/flutter (13480): 
E/flutter (13480): 
F/flutter (13480): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(1201)] Check failed: fml::jni::CheckException(env). 
F/libc    (13480): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 13480 (e.pinkdrive.app), pid 13480 (e.pinkdrive.app)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/dreamltexx/dreamlte:9/PPR1.180610.011/G950FXXUCDUD1:user/release-keys'
Revision: '10'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 13480, tid: 13480, name: e.pinkdrive.app  >>> de.pinkdrive.app <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(1201)] Check failed: fml::jni::CheckException(env). 
'
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000000000034a8  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000000000000008
    x4  0000000000000000  x5  0000000000000000  x6  0000000000000000  x7  8000000000000000
    x8  0000000000000083  x9  00000074cd77b838  x10 fffffff87ffffbdf  x11 0000000000000001
    x12 00000074064c2400  x13 0000000000000000  x14 ffffffffffffffff  x15 0000332faa758a24
    x16 00000074cd7b22a0  x17 00000074cd6f1920  x18 0000007ff5b273ea  x19 00000000000034a8
    x20 00000000000034a8  x21 0000000000000083  x22 000000000000003a  x23 0000007441ff6bf0
    x24 0000007441ff6bd8  x25 0000000000000000  x26 00000074cf3de5f8  x27 000000000000003a
    x28 0000000000000001  x29 0000007ff5b27ca0
    sp  0000007ff5b27c60  lr  00000074cd6e4d68  pc  00000074cd6e4d94
backtrace:
    #00 pc 0000000000021d94  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+124)
    #01 pc 000000000145a1dc  /data/app/de.pinkdrive.app-flT72br4XLMAqgR_wyKwmQ==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x1458000)
Lost connection to device.
```

Comment: how using `flutter clean` and rebuild? is there any error on `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: flutter doctor -v gives no issues,
But flutter clean throws:
Failed to remove build. A program may still be using a file in the directory or the directory itself. To find and stop such a program, see:

Tried to delete some process but could not find which

Comment: What happens when you try to delete `build` folder ?

Comment: Thanks! I could delete build, but after running one time on my s8 it crashed on the second time. 

Do I have to flutter clean every time?

Comment: i dont think it's the best way, try flutter upgrade.

Comment: it is working until now! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Yeasin Sheikh I just needed to delete the build folder, flutter clean and flutter upgrade!